# cakePHP "required" validation

Tags: cakephp, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, cakephp-1.3

is there any mistake in this validation???

```
 var $validate = array(
  'brand_id' => array(
   'required' => array(true),
   'message' => array('select a brand'),
  )
    );
```

brand_id is a select box
It show error as "message" instead of "select a brand"
if the message is not in array it shows error

```
Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash [CORE\cake\libs\model\model.php, line 2571]
```

using cakePHP 1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a **rule**, just `required` won't do. Use `'notEmpty'` as rule if that's what you want. Also, `required` and `message` should (must?) not be arrays.

Comment: @RSK That depends entirely on what the value should be. It doesn't matter that it's a select box, the rule is there to verify what values are allowed to go into your database and which aren't. Pick any rule that fits your bill: http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1143/Data-Validation#Core-Validation-Rules-1152

Comment: thanks dude comparison rule worked 'rule' => array('comparison', '>', 0),

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have arrays everywhere?

```
 var $validate = array(
  'brand_id' => array(
   'required' => true,
   'message' => 'select a brand',
  )
);
```

Refer to:
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html